# Nielsen Schreier Theorem

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

According to theorem if $H$ is a subgroup of index $m$ of a free Group $G$ of rank $n$, then $H$ is free and rank of $H$ is $nm+1-m$.

Now if $G= Z\times Z$ then it is free group of rank 2
 if $H= Z\times 2Z$ then $H$ is of index $2$ in G, then by theorem $H$ has rank $3$

but I know generators of $Z\times 2Z$ are $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$

What is wrong with me?

Comment: Those are not free groups. $G$ is a free abelian group, they are different things though and is not what Nielsen Schreier theorem is talking about.

Comment: @Paul Plummer sir can u tell me what is the difference between the both?

Comment: Being abelian puts the condition $xy=yx$, so it is not free.

Comment: Got it sir, very simple thing to understand.. thanks vanchinathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the groups are free abelian groups, they are not free groups as the theorem requires.